# ScrollViewProxy scrollTo() does nothing if the list is scrolling

Tags: swiftui

I have a list wrapped in a ScrollViewReader and have overlayed a button (updated to provide a complete demo)

```swift
struct Rows: View {
    
    var dataRows: [RowData] = []
    
    init() {
        for i in 0...1000 {
            dataRows.append(RowData(id: i))
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                List(dataRows) { row in
                    NavigationLink {
                    } label: {
                        Row(data: row)
                    }
                }
                Button("Scroll To Top") {
                    print("button pressed")
                    scrollView.scrollTo(0)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Row: View {
    var data: RowData
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(data.id))
    }
}

struct RowData: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
}
```

This all works as expected, I tap the button and the list is scrolled to row with id `0`

However if I flick the list, it scrolls and slowly decelerates over several seconds, during the time if I press the button the message is printed, but the list doesn't scroll back.

scrollTo only seems to work if the list has come to a complete stop

How can I halt the scrolling to get the button to work?

I can reproduce this in the simulator, but it sometimes works as I'd like - however on a real device (iPhone 12, iOS 17) the problem is always seen

Many thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue and it works as expected. Maybe you need to post the `//...rows` too

Comment: Thanks for looking - I'll try and build out the code!

Comment: I've updated the code, interesting the problem is less evident in the simulator, but is consistent on my iPhone 12 Pro (iOS 17)

Comment: I can't reproduce it on iPhone 12 and iOS 17 simulator.